# How to decide which authentication to use in multitenant environment?

Tags: asp.net-membership, multi-tenant, thinktecture-ident-server, sts-securitytokenservice

I am designing one Multi tenant based CRM system, Where tenant will be identified by sub domain. But I am a bit confuse about the authentication system, which one to use. STS using some third party tool like thinktecture Or simple membership provided by Microsoft framework.

Answer (score 0):

[Identity Server 3](https://identityserver.github.io/) (Thinktecture) will be your best bet.

Simple Membership is a fair bit out of date... See Brock Allen's article [Think twice about using MembershipProvider (and SimpleMembership)](http://brockallen.com/2012/09/02/think-twice-about-using-membershipprovider-and-simplemembership/) for a good argument against Simple Membership.

Comment: If you're still not convinced, have a look at asp.net identity (http://www.asp.net/identity) instead of SimpleMembership

Comment: Yeah, it's worthwhile noting that Identity Server 3 supports ASP.NET Identity or Membership Reboot as user stores out-of-the-box